# How to define environment variable in a same folder for multiple projects in a WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, dotenv

I have a few projects which run simultaneously by using WebStorm's compound feature, see screenshot below:
[image]

All these projects need the same environment variables which I'd like to define in a file **.env**. And I need multiple environments which I will switch between them constantly, let say **.test1.env**,  **.test2.env**, **.test3.env**, etc... ([I know that I shouldn't do this, but I have no choice right now](https://12factor.net/config))

How can I define my project in a way that on startup it will take **.env** file, which name will be defined **in a single place** and define environment variables from it for all the projects?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this, please follow [IDEA-137820](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137820) and linked tickets for updates